# Why this query on google sheets return error?

Tags: google-sheets

I've read tons of topics and tons of links about writing this query but keeps returning `#ERROR!`. I have no clue what's wrong, the query line I wrote is:

```
=QUERY(B2:B180;"SELECT "col3" WHERE "col2" CONTAINS "E2"";-1)
```

What's wrong?

If you want to know more about the problem:

I have a google form created to take a lists of objects that my team has, I want to put in a cell the keyword I'm searching and want excel to return me the name of all the people who owns that object, in normal excel I would write a `vba` probably but in google sheets I find it a way harder.

P.S. I tried to write the `col3` in other ways but seems he doesn't understand , while `E2` lights on the google sheets and seems it understood what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range is only one column (B2:B180) so there simply is no Col3. Also in this query, you should refer to columns by letter: "select B, C, ...".

Comment: i tried to use also B C etc doesn't work.. i corrected as u suggested : =QUERY(B2:C180;"SELECT C WHERE B CONTAINS "E2"";-1) ... Same error message where 's the mistake?

Comment: Assuming E2 contains a string (and not a number) the formula should look like  =QUERY(B2:C180;"SELECT C WHERE B CONTAINS '"&E2&"'";-1)

Comment: Most welcome @Eddo10957. If the answer helped, please upvote.